# How to hide a div with Jquery based on the elements inside it

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to hide one of the divs below, not its content. What is the jQuery selector I can use to target the div that has the input with the name `address1`?

What I'm trying to do is hide div with class `.snipcart-input` where it has an input with the id `address1`

```html
<div class="snipcart-input">
  <input id="address1" type="text" name="address1" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
<div class="snipcart-input">
  <input id="address2" type="text" name="address2" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:has()` selector to achieve what you need:

```js
$('.snipcart-input:has(#address1)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snipcart-input">
  Address1: 
  <input id="address1" type="text" name="address1" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
<div class="snipcart-input">
  Address2: 
  <input id="address2" type="text" name="address2" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) & [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/). `each` will iterate all the div with this class and will `find` input this `id`. This will give an object which have `length` property. So if that object have child with specified requirement then length will be more than 1. You can use `hide` or `addClass` to hide element

```js
$('.snipcart-input').each(function(i, v) {
  let hasChildrenWithId = $(v).find('input#address1');
  if (hasChildrenWithId.length > 0) {
    $(v).addClass('hide')
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snipcart-input">
  <input id="address1" type="text" name="address1" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
<div class="snipcart-input">
  <input id="address2" type="text" name="address2" class="snipcart-input__input snipcart__font--secondary snipcart__font--bold">
</div>
```